# Siblings in top-level of genealogytree, without extra space

Tags: genealogytree, genealogy

There are siblings in the top level of a genealogy tree (because their parents are unknown or irrelevant). How can I best make this tree with the package genealogytree? The example shows one tree with a parent and one without. In the latter one there is a parent set as `[phantom]`. The problem is that this takes up space, which can be seen from the distance between the header and the tree.

Omitting the parent (or using `[ignore]` on it) yields a "No g-node in child family" error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
\section{With parent}
\begin{genealogypicture}
  child{
    g{Parent}
    c{One}
    c{Two}
  }
\end{genealogypicture}

\section{Without parent}
\begin{genealogypicture}
  child{
    g[phantom]{Parent}
    c{One}
    c{Two}
  }
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If there is no prior generation that you can document, is it acceptable for you to pair the siblings at the base of the boxes rather than across the top? If they can be connected at the base then you can just interpret "One" and "Two" as parents with the ability to grow the tree downwards using the syntax setout in p14 of the `genealogytree` manual.

Comment: No, that indicates something else, and the siblings normally have their own descendants, even though they are omitted in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do note that I do not know this package at all, really. I certainly do not know it well enough to know if this template may have unwanted side-effects.

## *Caveat emptor ...*

---

We define a minimal `template`, `orphaned` for use when a tree has no parent at the root.

```
\gtruselibrary{templates}
\gtrset{% based on part of the package's code for the template ahnentafel 3
  template/orphaned/.style={
    level 0/.style={
      level size=0pt,
      node size=0pt,
      parent distance=0pt,
      further distance=0pt,
    },
  },
}
```

We can then say, for example,

```
\begin{genealogypicture}[template=orphaned]
  child{
    g[phantom]{}
    c{One}
    c{Two}
    child{
      g{Three}
      c{Four}
      c{Five}
    }
  }
\end{genealogypicture}
```

to produce

[image: orphaned tree]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{genealogytree}
\gtruselibrary{templates}
\gtrset{% based on part of the package's code for the template ahnentafel 3
  template/orphaned/.style={
    level 0/.style={
      level size=0pt,
      node size=0pt,
      parent distance=0pt,
      further distance=0pt,
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\section{With parent}
\begin{genealogypicture}
  child{
    g{Parent}
    c{One}
    c{Two}
  }
\end{genealogypicture}
\section{Without parent}
\begin{genealogypicture}[template=orphaned]
  child{
    g[phantom]{}
    c{One}
    c{Two}
    child{
      g{Three}
      c{Four}
      c{Five}
    }
  }
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{document}
```